# why there is error on cancel qfiledialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pycharm

That is my code

```
def report_one_friend(self):

filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "", "cars.xlsx","Excel(.xlsx)")

if filename:
    openFile = open(filename, 'r').read()
    self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(openFile)



wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename[0])
sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet()
sql = '''SELECT * FROM ahmed WHERE mth_search = %s'''
mth_search = self.lineEdit_3.text()
c = self.conn.cursor()
c.execute(sql, [(mth_search)])
data = c.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print(row)
    sheet1.write(0,2,'الاسم')
    sheet1.write(0,0,row[1])

    sheet1.write(1, 2, 'الرقم')
    sheet1.write(1, 0, row[2])

wb.close()
```

and that gives me an error :

```
 Connected to MySQL database using C extension... MySQL Server version on  8.0.12
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/mahmoudtarek/Desktop/mth1/index.py", line 174, in mth_friends
        self.report_one_friend()
      File "/Users/mahmoudtarek/Desktop/mth1/index.py", line 208, in report_one_friend
        openFile = open(filename, 'r').read()
    TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

Comment: You need to `print(filename)` and see what value you get. This is basic debugging that you can do on your end.

Comment: that : ('', '')

Comment: Are you sure? It's not `("",)`?

Comment: No : I use that code :- 
 filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "","cars.xlsx","Excel(.xlsx)")
        print(filename)

Comment: it gives me ('', '')

Comment: Ah, `('', '')`. Without the code formatting, that looked like double quotes. You're getting back a tuple of empty strings

Comment: yes, what I can do to solve that problem as the app is closed error after cancel choice

Comment: That I don't know, but you know now at least what you are getting as a result.

Comment: ok , thanks you @roganjosh

Answer (score 0):

you get a tuple of "the selected file" and "the applied filter".

minimal code example:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
app = QApplication([])
print(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName())
```

selected "some file":
`('C:/scratches/scratch.py', 'All Files (*)')`

But when you dont select something and cancel the dialog, then the two strings are empty: `('', '')`.
Because a tuple with two strings in it is `true`, you try to `open()` a file with this, which leads to you error.

---

**Solution:**
unpack the tuple into two variables or use index[0] like in the following:

```
filename, filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "", "cars.xlsx","Excel(.xlsx)")
if filename:
    openFile = open(filename, 'r').read()
    ...
```